# Returning data in PHP returns Null

Tags: php

I am storing the returned data from a query in this private `$_data` variable.

When I use the `$ticket->find()` function it is returning data.

When I use `$ticket->data()` it returns null.

Why would this be if they are both returning the same variable? How can I make `data()` return AND display the data?

```
<?php
class Ticket {
  public $_db,
         $_data;

  public function __construct($ticket = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
  }

  public function create($fields = array()) {
    if(!$this->_db->insert('tickets', $fields)) {
      throw new Exception('There was a problem creating a ticket.');
    }
  }

  public function find() {
    $data = $this->_db->get('tickets', array('uid', '=', '18'));
    $this->_data = $data;
    return $this->_data;
  }

  public function data() {
    return $this->_data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the piece of code where you call `$ticket->find()` and `$ticket->data()`?

Comment: your `ticket->data()` will only return anything if `ticket->find()` has been called first, otherwise the value of the `$_data` variable in your `Ticket` class is indeed null, as nothing assigns it a value.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan just using `var_dump($ticket->find())` and `var_dump($ticket->data())` to see what they are returning.

Comment: @TrentonTyler and if you do them by themselves rather then calling `find()` before `data()`, `find()` will work but `data` will not. Your `find` function gives `$_data` a value, whereas your `data()` function does not.

Comment: [A recreation of your code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3cf3c56c6c9624d82e599a306922f66e7dd8c2d) works just fine.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan you were right to assume that the code using this class is incorrect. The OP is most likely trying to directly summon the `data()` function after instantiating the class rather then to call the `find()` function first which actually assigns value to the `$_data` variable.